# How to get File Owner attribute from SAMBA (CIFS)?

Tags: java-7, samba, nfs, jcifs, fileshare

In my developing code, i have to bring file owner attribute from SAMBA server "CIFS"- File Share. How would i can get it by using any API within JAVA.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JCIFS version 1.3.18 has a patch available to get the owner of a file.

Link to the JCIFS java lib is : https://jcifs.samba.org/src/jcifs-1.3.18.jar

Link to the patch file is :https://jcifs.samba.org/src/patches/GetOwnerSid.patch

You have to get the source of the 1.3.18 version and then generate the JAR after applying the patch. Also, note that this patch does not resolve the SID of the owner. So you may want to add code to resolve the SID.

Answer (score 1):

I have used ACE & SID classes of jcifs jar to get owner id of smbFile. Using the same method anyone can get the sid, domain name, domain sid and etc... In the following method i needed only owner id which is retrieved from account name of SID.

```
public String retrieveOwnerIdOfFile(SmbFile smbFile) throws IOException {

    String userName = "";
    SID sid = null;

    ACE[] acl = smbFile.getSecurity(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < acl.length; i++) {
        sid = acl[i].getSID();
        if (sid.getType() == 1 && sid.getTypeText().equalsIgnoreCase("user")
                && sid.getAccountName() != null) {
            userName = sid.getAccountName();
            break;
        }
    }

    return userName;
}
```